# Entity framework creating separate database corresponding to each class in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have start using of Entity framework in ASP.NET MVC4.

I have created 3 classes in my `Model` folder and created controllers for every model.

Now when I run the application, it has created separate databases corresponding to every class of model.

Is there any way that we can use only one database?

Comment: How is your context defined?

Comment: Please post your context class.

Comment: My Context classes are like-
'public class EmployeeDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }'

Comment: My Context classes are like-
1. 
Here is my model class

`public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmpId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Designation { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ContactNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Here is my context class

Comment: Here is my context class

`public class EmployeeDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: @NamanGoyal - Edit your answer, don't post additional information as comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you creating a separate context for each of the classes?

```
public class Employee 
{
    [Key] public int EmpId { get; set; } // < Can I make a suggestion here
                                         // and suggest you use Id rather than
                                         // EmpId?  It looks better referring to 
                                         // employee.Id rather than employee.EmpId
    [Required] public string Fullname { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    ...
}
```

And then listing all your models in the context:

```
public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AnotherClass> AnotherClasses { get; set; }
}
```

You may also want to specify the connection string name by using a constructor in your Context:

```
public MyDbContext() : base("ConnectionString") {  }
```

It's important that all your models go in the same context.

**Using the context**

```
var context = new MyDbContext();
var employees = context.employees.ToList(); // I prefer storing the data as an IList
```

This tells EF to query the database and store the data within the employees variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
You are saying that I should create all the DbSet in a single class.
But I think, if I create object of 'MyDbContext' class than it will allocate memory to all the DbSets in that class.
Let me know, if I am wrong or if I am thinking right, how can we avoid this.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood how ef works.  When you use context.employees.ToList() it is at this point it queries the database and uses memory.  Having it listed within the one class doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Now I got it.